# Can I combine Shapley scores?

Tags: shapley-value

I'm working in a context where some of the feature engineering on a dataset is done in one step of the pipeline and then different models are run on this feature engineered dataset. The problem is that using SHAP on these models gives us multiple Shapley values for fields that would be better as one value.

For example, if we have a categorical variable `color` with values `r, b, g, y` and this get one-hot encoded as `color_r`, `color_b`, `color_g`, and `color_y`. Then, each of these will get a different Shapley value for each color. Is there a way to combine these to get a Shapley value for `color`. If, as I suspect, this is not possible, is there a way to get a good/decent approximation.

Note: this also comes up with our text fields since we break it up into n-grams.

Comment: ever got anywhere with this? there is this: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/282

Answer (score 1):

One of the crucial properties of SHAP values is their additivity. Thus, you can sum up (row-wise) the SHAP values of the OHE columns.